# How do I toggle the `disable` attribute to my dropdown-menu base on what I have in my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown-menu of 5 options.

```
<select id="dd">
 <option value="1"> 1 <option>
 <option value="2"> 2 <option>
 <option value="3"> 3 <option>
 <option value="4"> 4 <option>
 <option value="5"> 5 <option>
</select>
```

I have an **array** that I need to check it against my dropdown-menu value

`var enable = [1,3,5];`

I want to produce this

```
<select id="dd">
  <option value="1"> 1 <option>
  <option value="2" disabled="disabled"> 2 <option>
  <option value="3"> 3 <option>
  <option value="4" disabled="disabled"> 4 <option>
  <option value="5" > 5 <option>
</select>
```

How can I disable my 2, and 4 option ?

I only want to enable 1,3 and 5 .

I'm a little stuck here.

```
$("#dd > option").each(function() {
    if(  inArray(this.val(),studentsArray ) !== -1 ){
        //prop the disabled attribute
    }
});
```

Can someone please give me a little push here ?

Comment: Your question can be answered by a simple Google search using the term "[html disable option](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp)".  Please do your research first before asking questions.

Comment: @Kathy, I know how to do that in html. just added the `disable` attribute. But I just don't know how to loop through all my options, and trigger that.

Comment: If someone here has satisfactorily answered your question, please take the time to accept their answer by selecting the check next to the answer. If there are no satisfactory answers, edit your question for more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it right in HTML like this:

```
<select id="dd">
  <option value="1"> 1 <option>
  <option value="2" disabled="disabled"> 2 <option>
  <option value="3"> 3 <option>
  <option value="4" disabled="disabled"> 4 <option>
  <option value="5" disabled="disabled"> 5 <option>
</select>
```

Note that disabled="disabled" is XHTML style. Plain old disabled by itself as others have posted will work fine too.

If your disabled options will always be the same, this will work. But if you want to use jQuery to disable all options not in the array, you can do this:

```
var array = [1, 3];
$('#dd option').prop('disabled', true); // Disables all
for (var i in array) { // Iterates over array
    $('#dd option[value="' + array[i] + '"]').prop('disabled', false); // Enable this one option
}
```

Comment: Now someone, know what I'm talking about.

Comment: OP, it appears you un-selected this as your chosen answer. Is there a problem with this answer? Fiddle proving that my solution works: https://jsfiddle.net/6em3rsbv/

Answer (score 1):

I am completely re-writing this answer of mine, because I have a much better answer. To change whether an option is disabled or not, give it an Id, or if there are several options to be disabled, give them all the same class. For an Id, (one element to be disabled only) do this:

```
variableName=document.getElementById('id');
//where 'id' in the line above is the id of the option to be disabled
variableName.setAttribute('disabled, 'disabled');
```

or for a class, it is very similar

```
optionstobechanged=document.getElementsByClassName('class');
//where 'class' in the line above is the name of the class given to the items to be disabled
for(i=0; i<optionstobechanged.length; i++){
    optionstobechanged[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

note that this can be recycled for similar things. The

```
setAttribute();
```

function takes two strings: the property/attribute to be changed(i.e. selected, disabled) and the value of it. so

```
.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

comes out as

```
disabled='disabled'
```

you can also apply this to selected, and other attributes. Now, all you have to do is rig this up inside a function and call it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asks how to disable select options - your solution hides them entirely.

Comment: @MatteoC define 'disabling them'. He clearly accepted it, given his upvote and comments.

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon: "Disabling them" means adding a "disabled" property to the options. The OP accepted my solution when it was initially posted but then un-accepted it today (note the lack of a green check mark.)